# Adding service/endpoint behaviors to multiple services through config

Tags: c#, wcf

In my project, there are multiple WCF services exposed. I want to add a service and endpoint behaviors to all of these services.
I have created these behaviors like below.

```
<behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RequestInspectorBehavior">
          <RequestInspectorBehaviorExtension />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webby">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <RequestInspectorBehaviorExtension />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Now one option is, I can add these to my individual services like below.

```
<service name="Service1" behaviorConfiguration="webby">
<endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="RequestInspectorBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="CONTRACT_GOES_HERE" />
```

But what I would like to know that is there a way I can provide this service and endpoint behaviors to all my services without explicitly adding these via names for each service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With WCF 4.0+, you can set a behavior as the default for all services and/or endpoints by omitting the `name` attribute in the appropriate behavior section of your config.  This is also true for bindings.

In your situation, the following should work:

```
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <RequestInspectorBehaviorExtension />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <RequestInspectorBehaviorExtension />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

As both the endpoint and service behaviors do not have a `name` attribute, they will be used for as the default for *all* service and endpoint behaviors.

So your service and endpoint definitions would look like this:

```
<service name="Service1">
  <endpoint address="" 
            binding="webHttpBinding" 
            contract="CONTRACT_GOES_HERE" />
```

If you have a service or endpoint that needs something other than the defaults you defined, you simply add definitions and then reference them in the service or endpoint element's appropriate attribute.

Default endpoints, bindings and behaviors are very powerful and useful (though they've caused their share of headaches as well).  For more information you can take a look at [A Developer's Introduction To Windows Communication Foundation 4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx).